# iOS 17 Force Screen Rotation not working on iPAD only

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, ios17

I have followed all the links on Google and StackOverFlow, unfortunately, I could not find any reliable solution **Specifically for iPad devices**.

I am using the sample code from [Kodeco UISplitViewController](https://www.kodeco.com/4613809-uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started). You can download the source code from here and add a UIButton.

I added a Button and added a code for **WindowScene RequestGeometryUpdate** function.

**So, please I need help to Rotate iPad Screen when Pressed on Button.** I have attached **Error Console Message when pressed on a Button**.

**Your help will be greatly appreciated.**

```
@IBAction func btnSelector(_ sender: Any) {
    self.rotateToLandsScapeDevice()
}

func rotateToLandsScapeDevice(){
                                
    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscapeLeft), errorHandler: { error in
            print("Error", error)
        })
        self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }

}
```

**Error Console Message**

```
Error Domain=UISceneErrorDomain Code=101 "The current windowing mode 
does not allow for programmatic changes to interface orientation." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current windowing 
mode does not allow for programmatic changes to interface orientation.}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)" and set the item to "Portrait (**bottom home button**)" in your info.plist file like that

[image]

Comment: This is already in the Plist file. This is Specifically not working for iPad. And all the orientation is supported in iPad and already added to the Plist.

You can download the sample code from Kodeco and here is the link and click on Download Material: https://www.kodeco.com/4613809-uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. It seems like there is conflict between `Upside Down` and `Landscape` here. In `Info` tab, unchecking the iPad Orientation state `Upside Down` could fix the problem.

[image]

Output:

[image]